# Can't get value from my span element

Tags: javascript

I have such span element in my document:

```
<span id="countdown-box">3</span>
```

and this is my javascript code in first version, in this case 3 is given, and counting down from 3 to zero, that not a surprise:

```
var timeleft = 3;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdown-box").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
}, 1000);
```

but instead of giving value as a constant number to variable timeleft, I want to get it from that span element at the beggining, and than countdown to 0.

Something like that, but it doesn't work...

```
var timeleft = document.getElementById("countdown-box").textContent;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdown-box").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
}, 1000);
```

1) variable `timeleft`gets value from span element, now I should have 3 in `timeleft`. Then `timeleft` is decremented and every time after that span element is updated till it's 0. This is how I understand it.
I was also trying with parseInt() or Number() but in this case counting down doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  https://jsfiddle.net/6yjsru8r/

Comment: It works for me. You should check it again. http://jsfiddle.net/92y4dqcL/

Comment: Only first version works fine - counting down from 3 to 0 when 3 is given. But in second version, when 3 is is not given, but I'm trying to get it from span it doesn't work, its 3 and doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't retrieving the value from the span any further. Once it's in `timeleft`, you are modifying `timeleft`, not the value of the span.

Comment: So how can I:
1) red value from spania element, it can be various sometimes 3 but sometimes 7 etc.
2) in same span element start countind down every second to zero.

Answer (score -1):

Solved...

```
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("countdown-box").textContent--;
    if (document.getElementById("countdown-box").textContent <= 0)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
}, 1000);
```

No it's working like I want. Sorry.